# Typescript on node.js stream - incorrectly extends base class 'Transform'

Tags: javascript, typescript, node.js-stream

```
import { Transform } from "stream";    
export class TestStream extends Transform {

        constructor(options) {
            super(options);
        }

        write(data: any, enc: string, cb: Function) {
            return super.write(data, enc, cb);
        }
    }
```

I'm getting following error on the above code.

**Class 'TestStream' incorrectly extends base class 'Transform'.
  Types of property 'write' are incompatible.
    Type '(data: any, enc: string, cb: Function) => boolean' is not assignable to type '{ (chunk: any, cb?: Function): boolean; (chunk: any, encoding?: string, cb?: Function): boolean; }'.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `write` supports the following overloads:

```
write(chunk: any, cb?: Function): boolean;
write(chunk: any, encoding?: string, cb?: Function): boolean;
```

The second parameter could be either encoding or callback. You have to handle it in your code:

```
write(chunk: any, encodingOrCB?: string | Function, cb?: Function): boolean {
    if (typeof encodingOrCB == "string") {
        return super.write(chunk, encodingOrCB, cb);
    }
    else {
        return super.write(chunk, encodingOrCB);
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are overriding the function `write` incorrectly.

try

```
write(data: any, enc?: string, cb?: Function) {
    return super.write(data, enc, cb);
}
```

Notice `?` it is used for optional parameters

Comment: Now I am getting additional `Types of parameters 'enc' and 'cb' are incompatible. Type 'Function' is not assignable to type 'string'.` in error message